# Jenkins not running automatic builds

Tags: jenkins

My periodically jenkins builds just stop running. I didnt make any configuration change and if I click to run it runs normally.

I'm using this time configuration: `0 2,5,8,11,14,17,20,23 * * *`

Jenkins version: `1.518`

Any idea?

Comment: It runs with you click build now, right? Any recent jenk/plugin update? Checked out any log from Jenkins?

Comment: /log shows some warnings about my nodes: `WARNING: Node monitoring machineName for Clock Difference aborted.` They are all with a 46secs clock lag.

Answer (score 0):

Go to http:// your_jenkins_url_here /computer/configure
And try to disable **Preventive Node Monitoring->Clock Difference**